# Excel Table lookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
       A         B  C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P
1 In Use        |1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0|
2 Item Value    |1  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0|
3 Data          |3  4   5   6   7   8   9   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8|
```

I'm looking for an excel function that will compare the values of Rows 1 and 2 to see if they both equal 1. If they are both 1, I would like for it to return the value of the third row (of the corresponding column who has both values equal to 1) to the cell. So in this example, I am looking for the function to return the value 3.

What is the best function to achieve the desired result? I have tried the `AND()` function like so:

```
=and(B1:P1=1,B2:P2=1,B3:P3,0)
```

Comment: Whether or not there is only 1 occurrence of 1/1 pairs makes a big difference here.

Comment: Yes, for my purposes I am assuming that there will only be one occurrence of a 1/1 pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this go in each column? Or are you looking for a single cell that sums them all? If you are looking for one formula to check everything, would this work?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:P1,B2:P2,B3:P3)
```

Note that this depends on the values being 1 or 0, and that only one pair of (1,1) exists.

Comment: I'm actually not looking to sum anything. I am simply looking to return the corresponding value in the third row from the appropriate column where one pair of (1,1) exists. So for example, if B1=1, B2=1, and B3=65, I would want to return 65. The function should be able to check a range of cells though. Since my data is set up through columns B:P, it should check each column for the pair and then return the value in the third row of the matching column.

Comment: @raphnguyen Yeah, this will actually do that, but it depends on the values being 1 or 0, and that there will only be a single column that contains two 1's. What happens is that all of the values in the first row are multiplied by the values in the second, leaving you with a bunch of 0s and a single 1 (where both numbers = 1). That array is then multiplied by the third row, so you get a bunch of zeros and the value that you want. The sum of that is then taken, which will result in a bunch of zeros plus your value, which should equal your desired value. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes perfect sense and was exactly what I was looking for! I was afraid I wouldn't be able to find an Excel function that would achieve this. Thanks so much!